# How to implement critical section on folder level?

Tags: file, critical-section

I need to prevent an instance of my app to modify a folder content when an another instance of my app is working with content of this folder. So I need to implement some kind of critical section on file system level. I think I should place some kind of lock-file in a directory I working with and consider this directory is locked if the lock-file exists. Is there better solution, like putting some kind of tags or attributes to folder on file system level or whatever? Is solution with lock-file good enough?

Comment: what if the user manually makes changes in the content; do you care about those changes?

Comment: Yes, any other process could change anything. But for now I'am looking for the way to lock folder in consideration that changes can be made by my app only.

Comment: do you care about everything in the folder or it's just about some files in it

Comment: Everything in the folder.